# How to use Unpivot properly

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

I am a beginner in SQL. I want to convert some columns into rows inside a view, this is my view:

```
SLPRSNID    ITEMNMBR        1       2       3     4     5
1           01-GOGUA-010    0       500     500   500   500
4           01-GOGUA-020    1850    3850    2350  4450  2450
```

I need:

```
SLPRSNID    ITEMNMBR        VOLUME
1           01-GOGUA-010    2000
4           01-GOGUA-020    14950
```

I used:

```
SELECT ITEMNMBR, VOLUMEN
FROM dbo.SOPPPTOVOL
UNPIVOT
(
    VOLUMEN
    FOR ITEMNMBR IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]) 
) AS UnPvt
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. using `APPLY`

   ```
   DECLARE @table table (
   SLPRSNID INT ,
   ITEMNMBR VARCHAR(50),
   [1] FLOAT,
   [2] FLOAT,
   [3] FLOAT,
   [4] FLOAT,
   [5] FLOAT
   )

   INSERT INTO @table 
    VALUES (1, '01-GOGUA-010', 0.00,500.00,500.00,500.00,500.00),
           (4, '01-GOGUA-020', 1850.0,3850.00,2350.00,4450.00,2450.00)


   SELECT T.SLPRSNID,T.ITEMNMBR, P.VOLUME
   FROM @table T
     CROSS APPLY 
           (
            SELECT SUM(X.VAL)
            FROM
               (
                VALUES  ([1]),([2]),([3]),([4]),([5])  
               ) X(VAL)
           ) P(VOLUME)
   ```
2. Using `UNPIVOT`

   ```
   DECLARE @table table (
   SLPRSNID INT ,
   ITEMNMBR VARCHAR(50),
   [1] FLOAT,
   [2] FLOAT,
   [3] FLOAT,
   [4] FLOAT,
   [5] FLOAT
   )

   INSERT INTO @table 
   VALUES (1, '01-GOGUA-010', 0.00,500.00,500.00,500.00,500.00),
          (4, '01-GOGUA-020', 1850.0,3850.00,2350.00,4450.00,2450.00)

   SELECT E.SLPRSNID , E.ITEMNMBR , SUM(E.VOL) VOLUME
   FROM @table T 
       UNPIVOT 
           (
           VOL FOR VALS IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]) 
           ) E
   GROUP BY  E.SLPRSNID , E.ITEMNMBR
   ```